# Client window hung with no visible cause

Tags: python, emacsclient, company-mode

I was editing some code in an Emacs client, when all of a sudden it stopped reacting to my input. If I killed the client and connected with a new one, I got a pretty strange behaviour:

- if I tried to open a file that has changed (due to `git rebase` operations in another terminal), Emacs warned me about this and asked me if I wanted to re-read the buffer’s file. It accepted and displayed my input in the minibuffer. After that it presented me an empty window, and stopped reacting
- if I tried to open any other file/directory, I got the same empty window with no reaction again
- if I opened an X-Windows version of Emacs client with any file, I got the same result. Furthermore, the menu items didn’t react to clicking and the X window didn’t react to its close button, Alt-F4, etc.

After this point, nothing happened. The minibuffer and all the other windows didn’t update, any input seemed to be discarded (C-x C-c, M-x, whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was writing this post I tried to simply press `C-g` if some background operation is in progress I am not aware of, and I got control back.

It turned out that [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/) hung somewhere. I was editing some Python code with a running Python instance (started with `M-x run-python`).

Comment: If you find a way to reproduce this, `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` in advance, and after `C-g` you should have a nice backtrace you can paste into a bug report.

Comment: Please accept your own answer if you're satisfied with it so that it will be marked as accepted.